# Get user-selected value from HTML5 dropdown list using C#

Tags: c#, html, drop-down-menu

I want my C# code to get the currently-selected option from an HTML5 dropdown list.  Our situation is perhaps a bit different from many others, since this is not a client-server web app, but rather a desktop app which uses HTML for its UI in order to be more portable to Linux.  To support this, we use an embedded Firefox browser with the Gecko engine.

I'm new to working with HTML using C#, and I can't seem to find the right API call for this.

The HTML looks like this:

```html
...
<div class="select">
  <select id="ddlMyOptions" name="ddlMyOptions">
    <option></option>
    <option>first choice</option>
    <option>second choice</option>
  </select>
</div>
...
```

And the C# code I'm using to try to access it is:

```
IHTMLElement selectElement = documentHTML.GetElementByID("ddlMyOptions");
string value = selectElement.Items[selectElement.SelectedIndex].Value;
string text = selectElement.Items[selectElement.SelectedIndex].Text;
```

This is based on examples I have seen from other posts, but those posts are using asp.net and in my case Items and SelectedIndex are not defined for selectElement.

Also, I have seen some posts about using Javascript, but I would prefer to keep this all in C#, if possible.

I looked at what it would take to have a callback method on the dropdown, so I could get the selected value whenever it changed and save it to an instance variable in my class, but I wasn't able to figure out how to specify the callback method, either.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The answer does of course depend on, how you display the html. What library/code do you use?

Comment: Sorry, @PoulBak, I forgot to mention that - I've updated my question, above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there were no answers to my question, I went ahead with a JavaScript solution:

```
function updateDDLSelection(elid) {
    var el = document.getElementById(""ddlMyOptions"");
    var val = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
    el.setAttribute('value', val);
}
```

Then, I had to change the HTML from what was shown above to this:

```
...
<div class="select">
  <select id="ddlMyOptions" name="ddlMyOptions" onchange=""updateDDLSelection(event)"">
    <option></option>
    <option>first choice</option>
    <option>second choice</option>
  </select>
</div>
...
```

And here's the revised C# code to get the value that was set by the JavaScript function:

```
IHTMLElement selectElement = documentHTML.GetElementByID("ddlMyOptions");
string value = selectElement.GetAttribute("value", 0).ToString();
```

Hope this is helpful to someone else who is in a similar situation...